# Amcharts5 column color via adapters

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, amcharts5

I am a beginner at developing with Angular.

I'm using amcharts5 for one of my projects, and I seem to be in a bit of a bind.

Referring to [their example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/#code), I tried making the XY chart with different column colours, where they use the following function to implement that:
I found an example where it's used like this:

```
series.columns.template.adapters.add('fill', (fill, target) => {
  return chart.get('colors').getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
});
```

Using this approach I do get the result correctly, but my code editor shows the following error: `Argument of type "O" is not assignable to parameter of type "RoundedRectangle"`.

Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Maybe this is a TSLint issue and not really an error? (Though `ng serve` does seem to complain about it as well).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and as workaround i applied a solution found to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884354/amcharts-v5-template-adapter-example-throws-an-error-when-runs-as-typescript-bu):
simply cast `target` to `any`

```
series.columns.template.adapters.add("fill", function (fill, target:any) {
  return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
});
```